# Assign elements correctly in LAMMPS output (xyz)

Tags: lammps, atomic-simulation-environment

I am trying to do LAMMPS calculations but I have noticed that when I dump to `.xyz` that ASE cannot read the elements because they are simply not output!  Is there a good way to specify elements to atoms in LAMMPS?

I am using the following dump command

```
dump dump_all all custom 20 output.xyz id type x y z vx vy vz fx fy f
```

The data file looks something like this as well

```
/scratch/tgmaxson/data (written by ASE)

45       atoms
3  atom types
0.0      8.4770495136049657  xlo xhi
0.0      8.5867434566153804  ylo yhi
0.0      8.8601981847873912  zlo zhi


Atoms

     1   0   3   0.0     0.19840304286794558      2.6071741694272772      7.2188474839438452
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate little bit on what do you mean by assigning elements to atoms?

Comment: Also, a observation about the choice of your *dump* argument, to have the output in.xyz format, I think you have to use something like - *dump dump_all all xyz 20 output.xyz*.